# can't send message when using yahoo email address account

Tags: php

I am attempting send a message from a contact form to send to the gmail address account. My problem is  that when i'm using yahoo email address it is not sending to the recipient gmail address account but when using gmail address account to send to the recipient gmail address account looks fine..

like this....

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['contact_name']) && isset($_POST['contact_email']) && isset($_POST['contact_num']) && isset($_POST['contact_text'])){
    $contact_name = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $contact_email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $contact_num = $_POST['contact_num'];
    $contact_text = $_POST['contact_text'];
    if (!empty($contact_name) && !empty($contact_email) && !empty($contact_num) && !empty($contact_text)){
        $to = 'jeffgamasan@gmail.com,life1trading@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact form submitted';
        $body = $contact_name."\n".$contact_text. "\n" .$contact_num;
        $headers = 'From: '.$contact_email;
    if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)){
       echo "<script>window.location.href='thankyou.php'</script>";

    }else{
        echo "<script>window.location.href='error.php'</script>";

    }

    }else{
        echo "<script>window.location.href='error.php'</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting with JavaScript?

Comment: Could be caused by spam filters. Generally when "From" doesn't match domain of server is a strike against when spam audit runs